# Does Google Cloud Storage support SPDY, Keep-Alive, pipelining or other ways to improve small object performance?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have ten million tiny objects to transfer with Google Cloud Storage. It is expensive to open a TCP connection perform the SSL handshake, upload the request and wait for the response for each request before issuing the next request.

How can I speed things up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage supports a variety of features that improve upload and download performance:

1. Use a thread or process pool to issue requests on many connections in parallel.
2. Use the Keep-Alive header to enable [persistent HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). This allows you to reuse the same connection after each request, which improves the performance of TCP and SSL.
3. [Pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) your requests. Send the second request while you are waiting for the response to your first request. You can do this on the same HTTP connection.
4. Use [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY), which can help reduce latency through compression, multiplexing and prioritization.